# Prove that the conditional entropy of a classical-quantum state is non-negative

Tags: quantum-state, entropy, information-theory, cq-states

Let $\rho_{XA}$ be a classical-quantum state, i.e., $\rho_{XA}  = \sum_{x} p(x)  |x\rangle \langle x|  \otimes \rho_A^x$.

How to prove that the conditional von Neumann entropy $S(X|A) = S(\rho_{XA}) - S(\rho_A)$ is non-negative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will use the [upper bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy#Properties) on the entropy of a mixture (for proof see for example theorem 11.10 on p.518 in [Nielsen & Chuang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Computation_and_Quantum_Information))

$$
S\left(\sum_k p_k \rho_k\right) \leq H(p) + \sum_k p_k S(\rho_k)\tag1
$$

where $H(p) = -\sum_k p_k \log p_k$.

---

Set $p_x := p(x)$. Note that if $|\psi_y^x\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $\rho_A^x$ associated to eigenvalue $q_y^x$ then $|x\rangle\otimes|\psi_y^x\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $\rho_{XA}$ associated to eigenvalue $p_x q_y^x$. Therefore

$$
\begin{align}
S(\rho_{XA}) &= -\sum_x \sum_y p_x q_y^x \log(p_x q_y^x) \\
&= -\sum_x p_x \log p_x - \sum_x p_x \sum_y q_y^x \log q_y^x \\
&= H(p) + \sum_x p_x S(\rho_A^x)\tag2.
\end{align}
$$

Next, compute $\rho_A$

$$
\rho_A = {\rm tr}_X \rho_{XA} = \sum_x p_x \rho_A^x
$$

and so

$$
S(\rho_A) = S\left(\sum_x p_x \rho_A^x\right)\tag3.
$$

Finally, recognize $(3)$ and $(2)$ as the left and right hand sides of $(1)$ with the appropriate substitution to get

$$
S(\rho_A) \leq H(p) + \sum_x p_x S(\rho_A^x) \\
0 \leq S(\rho_{XA}) - S(\rho_A)
$$

which is the desired inequality.

Comment: Nice answer! Could you please recheck equation 3? It seems there is a typo.

Comment: Thanks for catching! Fixed.